# Correct order for closing various JDBC objects

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, cursor

I have the following code sample:

```
try {
    conn = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    stm = conn.prepareCall("{? =" + query + "}");
    stm.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    if (params != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
            stm.setString(i + 2, params[i]);
    }
    //getting result set from cursor
    stm.execute();
    res = (ResultSet) stm.getObject(1);
    return DatabaseLayerUtils.getResultSetData(res);
} finally {
    //closing cursor
    if (res != null) res.close();
    if (stm != null) stm.close();
    if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
```

Is the elements order in `finally` section important or not?

Is the following code:

```
 if (res != null) res.close();
 if (stm != null) stm.close();
```

equal to:

```
 if (stm != null) stm.close();
 if (res != null) res.close();
```

or not?

In a project being worked on by my colleague there are a lot of constructions like:

```
 if (stm != null) stm.close();
 if (res != null) res.close();
```

I need to understand if this is the right syntax or if I need to fix as shown:

```
 if (res != null) res.close();
 if (stm != null) stm.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly close ResultSet and Statement if you close Connection. From what I know all JDBC drivers handle this properly now.

If you want to explicitly close them in a row then you need to close them in the reverse order of creation: ResultSet, Statement, Connection.

Also you need to wrap each close into try/catch, since they throw an exception as far as I remember.

Better, if you have some utlity class with `close(ResultSet rs)`, `close(Statement stmnt)` and `close(Connection cnn)` methods.

**UPD**

There is one more new (two years old already, heh) method to close JDBC (not limited to JDBC) stuff now.

Java7 introduces new feature called "try-with-resources" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

The tutorial (link above) is quite self-explanatory so I think noticing this feature is enough for now.

For the JDBC resources purpose, you can register Statement in try-with-resources and skip closing ResultSet (declare it as usual after `try .. {`) because that will happen automatically as I described in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the elements order in finally section important or not?

Yes. If you close the connection first, the other closes are redundant and can be omitted. If you want to close everything you should do so in reverse order of acquisition.

For maximum clarity and flexibility I do it like this:

```
Connection conn = ...;
try
{
  PreparedStatement ps  = ...;
  try
  {
    // ps.setXXXXX() ...
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    try
    {
      // ...
    }
    finally
    {
      rs.close();
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    ps.close();
  }
}
finally
{
  conn.close();
}
```

Then I can sleep at night knowing there is no escape ;-) No null tests necessary either.

Comment: Out of curiosity: any reason you didn't use/show try-with-resources?